# Swift Package: Dependent Package can't be found. Remedy?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift-package-manager

**Background:**  I made a [successful package <--- dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68413060/swift-package-build-failure-remedy) earlier today using a different dependency as a 'proof of concept'.

However the **Facebook SDK package** dependency failed to be recognized:

[image]

Here is the package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CVSFacebookAccess",
    platforms: [
           .iOS(.v13)
       ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "CVSFacebookAccess",
            targets: ["CVSFacebookAccess"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Facebook", url: "https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git", from: "11.0.1")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "CVSFacebookAccess",
            dependencies: ["Facebook"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "CVSFacebookAccessTests",
            dependencies: ["CVSFacebookAccess"])
    ]
)
```

Here's the Facebook package:

[image]

**Question:** 
Why can't the Facebook SDK be recognized? 
I'm following the same [Swift PM syntax as before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68413060/swift-package-build-failure-remedy).

Comment: I'm a neophyte here.  I'm writing the Swift Package for my client.  The 'App' is a package; NOT a full App.   I intend to integrate the package into an App as the entry point into the Facebook world.  So the Swift Package would be a stand alone entity used by apps.  Any required registration could be thru my custom package; if that makes sense.  That is, user agnostic (if that's possible).

Comment: I did attempt to build the package using the same name as a registered Facebook app but no different outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook SDK for iOS package includes several libraries such as: `FacebookCore`, `FacebookLogin`, `FacebookShare`, `FacebookGamingServices` and you should make a dependency to a needed one e.g.:

```swift
...
.target(
    name: "YourPackage",
    dependencies: [.product(name: "FacebookLogin", package: "Facebook")]),
...
```

Then you can use this library in your code:

```swift
import FBSDKLoginKit

func createLoginButton() -> FBLoginButton {
    return FBLoginButton()
}
```